# Automated Notification of the expiry of Service Account Keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, gcp-iam

We have a lot of user managed SA keys with a set expiry date & we want to get the notification of expiry keys via email & would like to receive a notification of service account keys expiration days before they do expire.

Comment: You will need to write that feature (Cloud Schedule + Cloud Functions). AFAIK there is no reporting/monitoring/messaging API on key expiration.

Comment: This should really be an enhancement request.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for "Cloud Run".

I'd implement this as a daily cloud run job that parses service accounts once a day looking for the expiry and acting accordingly, emailing, or publishing to pubsub or some such thing.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler.

My goto language is python, and that would be trivial, but you can whip this up in an array of languages.